# How to get the number of items in a spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

How to get the number of items in a spinner dynamically?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can try:

```
mSpinner.getAdapter().getCount();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
spinerObj.getAdapter.getCount();
```

**for getting number of item**

Comment: should getAdapter have parenthesis?

Answer (score 6):

`spinnerAdapter.getCount();` or `spinnerList.size();`

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin:

```
val spinnerCtr = binding.spinnerName.count
```

produces the number of list items. It starts at zero.