# How to set a spinner selection back to its first item after using incremental operAtor

Tags: java, android

Working with two spinner object that uses item from same string-array.i want to increment the other spinner(say spinner2) if the currentspinner(say spinner1) selected item is same as the item on (spinner2). 
Main

```
    import android.support.v7.*;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner1,spinner2;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    int position1,position2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.items,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                position1=parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    if (position1==position2){
                        position2++;
                    }



                spinner2.setSelection(position2);


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                position2=parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
                if (position2==position1){
                    position1++;
                }
                spinner1.setSelection(position1);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

My issue is that any time both spinner is set to the last item(Inch). The app forces closes. And I want it to set the other spinner to the first item.Pls help me. Thanks in advance.

```
String-array<resources>
<string name="app_name">About Spinner</string>
<string-array name="items">
    <item>Metre</item>
    <item>Kilometre</item>
    <item>Centimetre</item>
    <item>Millimetre</item>
    <item>Miles</item>
    <item>Yards</item>
    <item>Foot</item>
    <item>Nanometre</item>
    <item>Nautical Miles</item>
    <item>Inch</item>

</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

so your problem can be solved with a simple if statement to catch when position goes out index overflow due to max spinner [size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467326/how-to-get-the-number-of-items-in-a-spinner)see below, just do the same for spinner2 and position1.

```
position1=parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    if (position1==position2){
                        If ((position2+1) > spinner2.getAdapter.getCount())
                           position2 = 0;
                        else
                           position2++;
                    }
```